# How to locate culprit for "Please correct the XML data and try again" error

Tags: magento2, layout, layout-update

Getting the following error on the cart page of Magento 2, `checkout_cart_index`. It's a code base with no version control and this issue is present even when I'm using the default Luma theme. I've run diffs between the original version, re-updated everything with Composer, but I didn't see any core files (app code and theme) modified.

> Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_7e13260053f56644d576f1e487266f9a1 
>       and handles default, checkout_cart_index: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

I've traced it back to...

```
Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge to
Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator to
Magento\Framework\Config\Dom.
```

However,  I still can't find the actual XML layout file with the schema violation. Is there a way to find out which file is the culprit without using an IDE like PhpStorm? (I tried a few online validators, but they did not return relevant errors)

Answer (score 0):

Basically no, even with an IDE. On Github ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3812 ) a Magento contributer **piotrekkaminski**  writes:

> it's a problem in most cases since validation is done on already merged file 
>   that no longer references the original files. We will add paths in places where 
>   it is possible.